# Java. Считать строки из файла

Tags: java, файлы, строки

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужно считать из .txt файла строки, которые выглядят так :

```
14 Февраля
10 Декабря
22 Июня
...
```

День считать в int переменную, название месяца в String переменную.
Никак не могу разобраться как это сделать?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("d:\\1.txt"));
while(sc.hasNext()){
    int tempDay = sc.nextInt();
    String tempMonth = sc.nextLine();
    theTree.insert(tempDay,tempMonth);//вставка данных в бинарное дерево
}
```

Comment: А как вы пытались?

Comment: На этом форуме принято показывать наработки вместе с вопросом. Для решения вашей задачи советую обратить внимание на [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) и [split()](http://proglang.su/java/strings-split)

Comment: @pinguin исправился, залил наработку. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("d:\\1.txt"));
int tempDay;
String [] splitted;
String tempMonth;
while(sc.hasNext()){
    splitted = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    tempDay = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
    tempMonth = splitted[1];
    theTree.insert(tempDay,tempMonth);//вставка данных в бинарное дерево
}
```

[пример работы](https://ideone.com/kO7siF)

UPD: Проверил у себя чтение из файла – все работает:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        int tempDay;
        String [] splitted;
        String tempMonth;
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            splitted = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            tempDay = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
            tempMonth = splitted[1];
            System.out.println(tempDay + "," + tempMonth);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: не считывается.

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi в чем именно проблема? UPD. Исправил, забыл разделитель передать в split()

Comment: из клавиатуры отлично читает и выводит, а от с файла не хочет. Не помогу понять почему

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi вообще ничего не выводит?

Comment: вообще, если с клавиатуры то выводит, а с файла нет

Comment: не знаете почему? последнее что осталось сделать :с

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi Проверил у себя чтение из файла – все работает

Comment: я нашел проблему, если в файле на англ написано - тогда все хорошо, если на рус - то ничего не выводит. Как считывать на рус?

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi перед чтением строк добавьте команду sc.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator())

Comment: @Виктор не помогло

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi тогда используйте BufferedReader, с ним такой проблемы нет. Заодно проверьте кодировку файла

Comment: @Виктор все, работает, всем спасибо!БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi у вас точно что-то не то  кодировкой файла, потому что я проверял на файле с русским и все работает

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать Scanner для большого количества скажем 10^5 уже будет выполняться более 1 секунды. Поэтому для больших данных лучше использовать StreamTokenizer. Вот пример работы.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Example_Read {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        StreamTokenizer reader = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt"))));
        while (reader.nextToken()!= StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
            int day = (int)reader.nval;
            reader.nextToken();
            String month = reader.sval;
            System.out.println(day + " " + month);
        }
    }
}
```